# Google Data Studio - Custom Field REGEXP_EXTRACT

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I am trying to use the REGEXP_EXTRACT custom field to pull a portion of my URL using the page dimension in Google Data Studio and cannot figure it out. The page url structure is similar to this -

website.forum.com/webforms/great_practiceinfo_part2.aspx?function=greatcoverage

I'd like to only extract the middle section "great_practiceinfo_part2". I've tried many different formulas, but nothing seems to work. Does the page dimension work in this scenario? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: if you show your formula, you will be helped much faster.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It seemed to work fine in Google Sheets when I `=REGEXEXTRACT(A3,B3)` using your string, `website.forum.com/webforms/great_practiceinfo_part2.aspx?function=greatcoverage` for `A3` and the regex `\/([^\/]*?)\.aspx\?` for `B3`.  I'm guessing you just need to learn more about how to make your regex pattern making string.